# How do i uninstall Mac OS after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, macbook, macbook-pro

I've decided to uninstall Mac OS from my MacBook Pro.

How do I remove the OSX partition after installing it with rEFInd?

Comment: Yeah you're right my bad, already edit my question thanks.

Comment: Delete the OSX partition.

Comment: yea but if i delete the partition it would be a diferent format partition i need it to be the same as the one i've installed ubuntu

Comment: So i got the solution from https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

Answer (score 2):

So i got the solution from https://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/
i just reformat the partition where Mac OS was install and then resize it with GParted, to do so i needed to got in to the pendrive that i used to install ubuntu and from there i could managed to resized my whole memory